# Imporing a function from a module in a package in python

Tags: python

I have a package named **'package'**
within that i have modules  
**module1.py** and 
**module2.py**
 i imported the package as

```
import package
from package import module1
```

In module1 i have a function named func
whenever i import that function as

```
from module1 import func
```

and use it, the function as

```
module1.func(x)
```

it doesn't work
What is the problem and what should be done??

Comment: Be more specific; what do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: You get an error? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either:

```
from module1 import func

func(x)
```

**OR**

```
 module1.func(x)
```

Real world example which should demonstrate how things work:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.abspath("C:/Documents")
'C:\\Documents'
>>>
>>> from os import path
>>> path.abspath("C:/documents")
'C:\\documents'
>>>
>>> from path import abspath
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named path
>>>
>>> from os.path import abspath
>>> abspath("C:/documents")
'C:\\documents'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either import as:

```
from foo import bar

bar(baz)
```

or:

```
import foo

foo.bar(baz)
```

In certain cases, it may also be helpful to:

```
from foo import bar as qux

qux(baz
```

There is an [extensive tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/modules.html#packages) on handling imports available as well.

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

```
from package.module1 import func
func(x)
```

2nd option:

```
from package import module1
module1.func(x)
```